# For Loop adding 5 numbers at a time

Tags: python

I have a file that contains a list of numbers ex:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

How would I be able to read the first five numbers, compute the sum, and then read in the next five numbers?  Could I use a for loop?  I want my answer to look like this:

```
var1 = 15
var2 = 40
```

Is there an easier way than using a for loop?

Comment: Hi, can you show us your sample implementation?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would probably be a for loop doing groups of 5 inside of a while loop going until there are no more integer values left to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `next` on the file handle and convert to integer, pass to `sum` in a generator comprehension, then unpack to 2 variables, with a default `0` value just in case the file ends before 10 values ([`next(f,0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) does that)

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
   var1,var2 = (sum(int(next(f,0)) for _ in range(5)) for _ in range(2))
```

Comment: This is certainly a good solution, can you add a link to `next` please.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind `for` loop in python is equivalent to `for each` conceptually. It would be better to use a `while` statement with a condition to stop reading after you have gotten the inputs you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the itertools [`grouper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=grouper#itertools-recipes) recipe, which is useful in lots of applications!

```
import itertools

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

sums = []

with open(filename) as f:
    groups = grouper(f)
    for group in groups:
        sum_ = sum(int(line) for line in group)
        sums.append(sum_)
```